# 'ClaimsToken' Error when trying to connect to SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: python, sql-server, authentication, azure-active-directory, ssas

I am facing an issue while trying to connect to SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. And also want to try to access it through some python code in the future to manipulate the data. When attempting to connect to the SSAS instance with an IP address, I receive an error message stating:

```
Cannot connect to "192.168.*.*". The integrated security 'ClaimsToken' is not supported for native connections. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)
```

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including checking the SQL Server Configuration Manager, ensuring the SSAS service is running, and verifying the firewall settings. However, I have not been able to resolve the issue yet.

Any assistance or suggestions to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Checked SQL Server Configuration Manager: I verified that the SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) service is running and configured correctly. The service appeared to be running without any apparent issues.

Verified Open Ports: To ensure that the firewall is not blocking the connection, I checked that the necessary ports for SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) are open. The required port, typically 1433, appeared to be accessible.

Attempted WMI Repository Verification and Repair: I ran the commands `winmgmt /verifyrepository` and `winmgmt /salvagerepository` in Command Prompt to verify and repair the WMI repository. However, this did not resolve the connection issue.

Comment: I realised that i also can't activate my Named Pipes https://imgur.com/a/iKXKpbF
Here is a screenshot of the error.